# Conversion failed when import events from eventlog to sql using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datetime, event-log

I'm trying to import events from Windows EventLog using wevtutil.exe handling data using powershell and import it to MS SQL database.
For Example:

```
$bulkcopy = new-object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy -argumentlist $connectionstring,$(<something>)
$dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$null = $dt.Columns.Add("EventID")
$null = $dt.Columns.Add("whenEvent")

[xml]$xml = (wevtutil /r:$nodename qe Security /e:Events /f:renderedxml /q:"*[System[(EventID=4722) or (EventID=4740)]]")
$xml.Events.Event | ForEach-Object {
  $row =$dt.NewRow()
  $row.Item("EventID")= $_.System.EventID
  $row.Item("whenEvent")= [datetime]$_.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
  $rt.Rows.Add($row)
  $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($dt)
}
```

When Event contains TimeCreated.SystemTime (real value) '2016-01-13T10:01:09.641338100Z' it works fine. But when Event created in (real value) '2016-01-13T10:58:08.550129100Z' it errors:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string."

I tried to use

```
$row.Item("whenEvent")=(Get-Date [datetime]$_.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime -f "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

but it always fall to exception:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column.

when i try

```
$row.Item("whenEvent")=$_.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime.ToDateTime()
```

it says

> Column 'whenEvent' does not allow DBNull.Value.
>   because it cannot be null.

How to convert datetime from eventlog correctly? MSSQL database field have type 'datetime'.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `-format` parameter of `Get-Date` you are actually specifying the output as a string, not a DateTime object:

```
PS:\> Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff" | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
...
```

So with `[datetime]$_.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime` you are casting the input date string to datetime then changing back to a string again with the -f parameter of Get-Date.

Try removing the format parameter.

Comment: And why use wevtutil? If you use the native PowerShell `Get-Eventlog`, then the `TimeGenerated` property is already a DateTime.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice! I tried few times with pre-formatting or not, it makes no sense. Problem was... in trigger on table which i adding data. Wevtutil a little bit faster in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Problem was in trigger after insert in table.